# Docker Redis start with persistent storage using -v gives error (chown: changing ownership of '.': Permission denied)

Tags: linux, docker, redis, dockerfile, redhat

I'm using following system version/spec for the [docker-redis](https://hub.docker.com/_/redis) setup using default [redis.conf](http://download.redis.io/redis-stable/redis.conf).

```
Redhat version: 7.6 (Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server)
Redis Version: 5.0.4
Docker Version:  1.13.1, build b2f74b2/1.13.1
```

When I run following command it's working perfectly fine.

```
sudo docker run -d -v $PWD/redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf --name redis-persistance --net tyk -p 7070:6379 redis redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf --appendonly yes
```

***I need to get redis data (which is in /data inside the container) to the host directory*** (/usr/local/etc/redis/data) **(-v $PWD/data:/data)**. So when I run following command I'm getting the below error. 
Note $PWD = /usr/local/etc/redis/

```
sudo docker run -d -v $PWD/redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf -v $PWD/data:/data --name redis-persistance --net tyk -p 7070:6379 redis redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf --appendonly yes
```

**Error in docker logs:**

```
journal: chown: changing ownership of '.': Permission denied
level=warning msg="05ce842f052e28566aed0e2eab32281138462cead771033790266ae145fce116 cleanup: failed to unmount secrets: invalid argument"
```

Also I tried changing the ownership of the **data** folder in the host to following as well. chown redis:redis data

```
drwxrwxrwx. 2 redis redis     6 May  3 07:11 data
```

Can someone help me out on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create a volume:

```
docker volume create redis_data
```

Check the volume is created (note the Mountpoint):

```
docker volume inspect redis_data
```

Then use this volume to start your container:

```
sudo docker run -d -v $PWD/redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf -v redis_data:/data --name redis-persistance --net tyk -p 7070:6379 redis redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf --appendonly yes
```

You can then check the contents of the "Mountpoint" that should be the redis data.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was adding a security contex like below to the deployment:

```
spec:
  securityContext:
    runAsUser: 999
    runAsGroup: 999
    fsGroup: 999
```

Then change the ownership of the mountpoint to 999 with:

```
chown -R 999:999 your_redis_mountpoint
```

Ofcourse you can use any UID other than 999.